# Why does this not out "invalid input" when i enter 4 / a in command arguments

Tags: c, command, arguments

Hi so i have this code and am really confused as to why it is not outputting invalid input, if i enter 4 / a into command argument, argc != 4 so therefore invalid input should be printed which is in the else statement? i also tried adding a separate statement but i could get that to work either. thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float numberOne;
    float numberTwo;
    float theResult;
    char action;

    sscanf(argv[1], "%f", &numberOne);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%c", &action);
    sscanf(argv[3], "%f", &numberTwo);

    if (argc == 4) {
        switch (action) {
        case '+' :
            printf("%f \n", numberOne + numberTwo);
            break;
        case '-' :
            printf("%f \n", numberOne - numberTwo);
            break;
        case '*' :
            printf("%f \n", numberOne * numberTwo);
            break;
        case '/' :
            theResult = numberOne / numberTwo;
            if (numberTwo == 0) {
                printf("invalid output");
                break;
            } else if (theResult == -0) {
                printf("invalid input");
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    } else {
        printf("invalid input");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

When I run it:

```
$ ./a.out 4 / a
$
```

Why doesn't it print "Invalid input"?

Comment: you should check the value of `argc` *before* you start looking at values in `argv`

Comment: I don't understand.  How are you calling your program on the command line?  You need to check the value of `argc` before your access particular members of the `argv` array.  If `argc` is 1 then `argv[2]` is accessing memory outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as the problem **you ask about** can't be reproduced -- you even show `argv` with 4 elements (0 - 3). But this code has another severe problem: why do you **first** access the arguments and only **later** check, whether they are actually there? This will be **undefined behavior** if too few arguments are given.

Comment: so if it enter "4 / a" into command arguments, argc == 3 so therefore the else from if statement prints invalid input. am i wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you call your program like

```
myprog 4 / a
```

then the `sscanf(argv[3], "%f", &numberTwo);` will fail and *no assignment will be made to* `numberTwo`. Because `numberTwo` is an *uninitialized local variable*, it can have any value and most likely not be `0.0`. Hence your check `if (numberTwo == 0)` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

`argc` is 4. You forget the name of the program, which is `argv[0]`.

Comment: i have argc is 4 and enter 3 thing into command argument

Comment: If you provide three items on the command line, `argc` is set to 4, because it also counts the program name. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Comment: @Squidly C arrays are 0-indexed. At index 0 of the argument list is the program name itself (by convention).

Comment: From the code the OP posted, I don't understand why you think the OP forgets `argv[0]` is the name of the program.  Looks like he/she intentionally skips `argv[0]` when assigning intermediate variables.

Comment: @MFisherKDX, OP says: "if i enter 4 / a into command argument, argc != 4". Which isn't so.

Comment: @MFisherKDX look at the title.

Comment: Hmm ... got it.  I missed the *a* of "4 / a".  That *a* doesn't make much sense with `%f`.

Comment: so if it enter "4 / a" into command arguments, argc == 3 so therefore the else from if statement prints invalid input. am i wrong?

Comment: @Squidly yes, you're wrong. Are you trolling?

Comment: This does not solve the problem

Comment: @klutt it answers the question. We can only *guess* what actual problem OP has...

Comment: @FelixPalmen The question was why it doesn't print `invalid input` when called with the arguments `4 / a`. This answer has absolutely nothing to do with that. The solution is to check the result of `sscanf`.

Comment: @klutt wrong. In the code, "invalid input" is only reached for argc != 4 which OP assumed would be the case.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Sorry for being (very) unclear. What I meant was that was insufficient to just have a look at `argc`. This answer gives a clue, but should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: @klutt still, no. It's a direct answer to the question. OP assumes `argc` was 3, this answer explains very brief it is 4. A *great* answer would of course mention and explain all the other problems in the code, but still they weren't asked about, and given the quality of this question, I also wouldn't be eager writing a great answer. IMHO, this question should be closed anyways.

Comment: @FelixPalmen You're probably right that it's best to close this. I wrote an answer now before I read this comment, but I'll leave this now.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to check the result of `sscanf`. It returns the number of items it successfully filled, so:

```
if(!sscanf(argv[1], "%f", &numberOne)) {
    printf("invalid input");
    exit(1);
}
```

should do the trick.

Furthermore, you should check `argc` *before* even touching `argv`. Move all `sscanf` inside the `if(argc == 4)` block. Same thing goes for checking the value of `numberTwo`. That should be done *before* the division.

It would also be a good idea to split error check and calculation. Here is a complete runnable example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float numberOne;
    float numberTwo;
    float theResult;
    char action;

    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("Wrong number of arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(!sscanf(argv[1], "%f", &numberOne)) {
        printf("Error reading argument 1\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(!sscanf(argv[2], "%c", &action)) {
        printf("Error reading argument 2\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(action != '+' && action != '-' && action != '*' && action != '/') {
        printf("%c is not a valid operation\n", action);
        exit(1);
    }

    if(!sscanf(argv[3], "%f", &numberTwo)) {
        printf("Error reading argument 3\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(numberTwo == 0.0 && action == '/') {
        printf("Division by zero\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Now we know that everything is alright */

    switch (action) {
    case '+' :
        printf("%f \n", numberOne + numberTwo);
        break;
    case '-' :
        printf("%f \n", numberOne - numberTwo);
        break;
    case '*' :
        printf("%f \n", numberOne * numberTwo);
        break;
    case '/' :
        printf("%f \n", numberOne / numberTwo);
        break;
    }

    return(0);
}
```